# How to convert LVLH-relative angular velocity to ECI-relative angular velocity?

Tags: flight-simulator, flight-mechanics

Suppose I have angular velocity of the LVLH frame relative to the Body frame, expressed in LVLH, how can I know what is the angular velocity of the Body frame relative to ECI, expressed in ECI?

I also have:

- The quaternion from ECI to Body
- The quaternion from LVLH to Body
- The ECI position
- The ECI velocity

Comment: you might consider defining the acronyms LVLH and ECI